# Window.location.href not works when url has # symbol in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup call which takes the user credentials and login the user. Usully user would like to same page after login also. That's way I want to refresh the current page.  I am using

```
 window.location.href="currentrul";
```

This works just fine when we don't have # symbol in url. Let's say my URL is something like http://www.test.com/faq#shipping, it won't works. Any suggestions are appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refresh the page, use:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because # signifies an anchor on the same page.

> The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional
>   last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a
>   portion of that document. The generic syntax is specified in RFC 3986.
>   The hash mark separator in URIs does not belong to the fragment
>   identifier.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mean, window.location.xxx will not workout to redirect the specific url, when url has "#" mark(fragment identifier)  in it...?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
if(currentURL.indexOf('#') != -1){
    currentURL = currentURL.substr(0, currentURL.indexOf('#'));
}
window.location.href = currentURL;
```

Comment: Appreciate your immediate reply. You mean, window.location.xxx will not workout to redirect the specific url, when url has "#" mark(fragment identifier)  in it...?

Comment: answer: "it depends".  In theory you are asking the browser to go to the page it is on and scroll to the anchor with that #name. A conservative browser (e.g. Firefox) says.. hmm no need to go to the network, just do the scroll part!  Unfortunately in this case that isn't likely what you want... you want a real reload.  thus if you reset the location.href (to just a "plain" URL) the browser (even Firefox) goes Ok... and reloads the page. (Note: if you really wanted to also scroll to that anchor, you'll need to handle that somehow)